# Showing $\langle 2x+1,5\rangle$ is a maximal ideal

Tags: ideals, integral-domain, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Consider the integral domain $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Show that the ideal $\langle 2x+1,5\rangle$ is a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

I need help with this problem I don't even know where to start since its not 1 generated its throwing me off as to how I should proceed in solving it any hints or help is greatly appreciated thank you.

Comment: Show that the quotient by the ideal is a field, the field with five elements more specifically. If you have a hard time with this, try it for the ideal generated by $x$ and $5$ first.

Comment: @quid could you explain a little more like I get that if I can show its a field then its maximal but how do I go about showing its a field like $\mathbb{Z}[x]/5$ I understand that this means functions with integer coefficients that have factors of 5. but that's 1 generated how do i think of it when it is two generated?

Comment: Try to prove that $\mathbb Z[x]/\langle x , 5 \rangle = \mathbb Z_5 [x]/\langle x \rangle$, for example.

Comment: Let us show as a warm up that $\langle X, 5 \rangle$ is a maximal ideal in your ring. 

Let $P$ in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$. Then you can write $P = c + X Q(X)$ for some integers $c$ and then $c= r  + 5q$ with $r \in \{0,1,2,3,4\}$. So $P = r + 5 q + X Q(X)$ and $5 q + X Q(X)$ is an element of $\langle X, 5 \rangle$. 

Thus $\mathbb{Z}[X] / \langle X, 5 \rangle $ has (at most) $5$ elements. It is not hard to show it actually has $5$ elements, and the quotient is the field with five elements. There is an extra complexity in your case as your polynomial has not leading coeff $1$ but answ explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that, for the Chinese Remainder Theorem, we have:$$\mathbb{Z[x]}/(2x+1,5)\cong\mathbb{Z_5[x]}/(2x+1)$$

Now we know that if R is an integral domain and I is a maximal ideal, R/I is a field.

$(2x+1)$ is a maximal ideal $\iff$ $2x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z_5[x]}$, which it is. So you have your thesis.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one direct proof. Note that $6x+3$ is in this ideal and therefore $x+3$ is in the ideal. It follows that any polynomial $p(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is congruent to an integer module the ideal. Now if we add any element to this ideal that is the same as adding an integer. If we add an integer not divisible by $5$, it will generate $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and thus the ideal is maximal.